# Как в Ansible преобразовать 2 списка в словарь?

Tags: администрирование, ansible, yaml

Есть 2 переменных:

```yaml
test2_dom_array:
  - example.com
  - example.org
test2_ip_array:
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 127.0.0.10
```

Как мне с помощью ansible сделать:

```json
[
  {
    "site": "example.com",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  {
    "site": "example.org",
    "ip": "127.0.0.10"
  }
]
```

У меня получается только:

```yaml
block:
  - set_fact:
      dig_fact: []
  - set_fact: 
      dig_fact: "{{ dig_fact + [{ 'site': item.0 },{ 'ip': item.1 }] }}"
```

с выхлопом:

```json
[
  {
    "site": "example.com"
  },
  {
    "ip": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  {
    "site": "example.org"
  },
  {
    "ip": "127.0.0.10"
  }
]
```

Comment: Возможно, поможет функция zip? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки нашёл как. Надо удалить 2 скобки в середине.

Как в вопросе:

```yaml
dig_fact: "{{ dig_fact + [{ 'site': item.0 },{ 'ip': item.1 }] }}"
```

Рабочий вариант:

```yaml
dig_fact: "{{ dig_fact + [{ 'site': item.0 , 'ip': item.1 }] }}"
```

-2 недели и +1 стыдная страница жизни :(